# Would a multithreaded Java application exploit a multi-core machine very well?

Tags: performance, multithreading, jvm, multicore

If I write a multi-threaded java application, will the JVM take care of utilizing all available cores? Do I have to do some work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you use a JVM that has so-called "green" threads (which is very few these days), Java threads are run by OS threads, so multiple threads get run on different cores by default.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up, I see 100% usage on both cores when I run this code on my dual core. If I bring the number of threads from two to one, one core goes to 100% and another about 4%.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreadTest
{
    public void startCPUHungryThread()
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThreadTest thread = new ThreadTest();
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            thread.startCPUHungryThread();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't guarentee that they will run on different cores.

Answer (score 2):

All modern JVMs will take advantage of as many cores as your hardware has. An easy way to illustrate this is to download and run the [DaCapo benchmark](http://dacapobench.org/) on your machine.  The lusearch benchmark uses 32 threads.  If you run this on your desktop or server, you should see all of your CPUs hit 100% utilization during the test.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion but instead of running the benchmark, I wrote a quick test class with two threads.

Answer (score 0):

On the flip of that, it is sometimes useful to "bound"/set affinity for a Java process to only use a set of cores/sockets, though done via OS semantics.  As previously answered, most runtimes indeed employ all cpus and with highly threaded apps can eat up more resources than you might expect.